# How to pass\user azure continue token via webAPI

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-cosmosdb

I use Azure with DocumentDB as my database.
I use the continue (paging) option for enable paging in search .
I received the following token from my database , and I want to pass that token to my client via WebAPI http.
the token is :
`"{\"token\":\"+RID:blablablabla==#RT:1#TRC:20#RTD:bOCA\",\"range\":{\"min\":\"\",\"max\":\"FF\"}}`

My problem is that when I send the token from my user I receive part of the token, so what I need to send to my remote client?
Thanks!!!
MAK

I solve the problem by sending the token in POST method instead in GET method add the token in the request body !

Comment: when you get it back from your client, you only get a partial token? how are you passing it from client to server?

Comment: Can you show us more detailed coding response that you generate from WebAPI?

Comment: I received the following error in my android application java.lang.IllegalStateException: not valid as a java.net.URI my token is: {"token":"+RID:blablablablablaAAAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:20#RTD:bOCA","range":{"min":"","max":"FF"}}

Comment: @woelliJ I received exception in my android application .In addition when I try to send the token via postman application , postman cut part of the token

Comment: how are you parsing the token? Sorry but you're just offering to little information. Please post all relevant code if possible

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you’d like to implement paging through query results via the [continuation token (x-ms-continuation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/query-documents). I do a test on my side to retrieve the next page of results from a query executed earlier, which works fine, please refer to it to construct the request.

[image]

***Resubmitting the request with the x-ms-continuation request header*** (cannot be used with a different query)

[image]

Comment: Hello , thanks for your comment. But I am not woking directly with the documentDB service . I pass via WebAPI2 service , that received the message and after some processing retrieve the information from the documentDB

Comment: Does your WebAPI return both query result and continuation token to the caller/client? the caller could maintain the continuation token in local storage and resubmit the request with the x-ms-continuation request header to do same query to get the next page result.